# How to use a specification pattern for my requirements?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, specification-pattern

I have read some examples of the specification pattern, but it is hard to get idea how to implement with this pattern.

I am developing a huge program for a client. I need to import XML files from a specific bank, then do validation with each of file. Ledger Codes has different methods (subs, bo, rcc). so when a file reads SUBS, it should send to a SUBS method.

Example here:

**Interfaces:**

- BlackBank
- BlueBank
- RedBank

**Ledger Codes:**

- SUBS
- BO
- RCC

**Result:**

- BlackBank has SUBS, BO and RCC
- BlueBank has SUBS
- RedBank has BO and RCC

Can you please give some example code or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your English isn't bad, you just need to learn how to ask a question better. There's example code [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern), maybe it would be better (not 100% sure) if you could explain what you don't understand about this?

Comment: I did read wikipedia, but it is too much to read and hard to understand. I prefer example code that matches my requirement. if you dont mind givng me example code :)

Comment: This is a pretty good code example (not your specific domain, but very illustrative): http://www.dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/139

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without context this is hard to answer so I will try making something up around the information I have and hopefully it'll give you an idea.

Create a simple specification interface like so

```
interface ISpecification<T>
{
    IsSatisfiedBy(T obj);
}
```

Pretending you have a base interface for 'banks' looking like

```
interface IBank
{
    LedgerCode LedgerCode { get; set; }
}
```

And an enum of LedgerCodes

```
[Flags]
enum LedgerCodes
{
    SUBS, BO, RCC
}
```

You can make a simple ledger code specification to check the LedgerCodes of an IBank (this is quite general you need to make it specific to your needs)

```
class LedgerCodeSpec : ISpecification<IBank>
{
    private LedgerCode code;

    public LedgerCodeSpecification(LedgerCode code)
    {
        this.code = code
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(IBank obj)
    {
        return obj.LedgerCode == code;
    }
}
```

Where appropriate you can use your specification, here I use it to provide simple validation. Another use is for 'selection' e.g. getting data from a repository

```
class Bank : IBank
{
    private ISpecification<IBank> spec;
    private LedgerCode code;

    public Bank(ISepcification<IBank> spec)
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.spec = spec;
    }

    public LedgerCode LedgerCode { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid 
    { 
        get
        {
            return spec.IsSatisfiedBy(this);
        }
    } 
}
```

And finally some code to quickly test/demonstrate the above

```
class Main
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var spec = new LedgerCodeSpec(LedgerCodes.SUB)
        var blueBank = new Bank(spec);

        Console.WriteLine(blueBank.IsValid); // false

        blueBank.LedgerCode = LedgerCodes.RCC | LedgerCodes.SUB;

        Console.WriteLine(blueBank.IsValid); // false

        blueBank.LedgerCode = LedgerCodes.SUB;

        Console.WriteLine(blueBank.IsValid); // true
    }
}
```

There are some nice examples on the web adding extension methods and also overriding operators to give a succinct and imo more naturally readable spec e.g.

```
class MessageSpecification : Specification<string>
{
    public const int MIN_LENGTH = 5;
    public const int MAX_LENGTH = 60;

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(string s)
    {
        Specification<string> length = new LengthSpecification(MIN_LENGTH, MAX_LENGTH);
        Specification<string> isNull = new IsNullSpecification<string>();

        Specification<string> spec = length && !isNull;

        return spec.IsSatisfiedBy(s);
    }
}
```

the way i'm currently using the pattern is probably overkill but i like the idea of removing, reusing and generally making the logic more OO.

Edit: after reading some of the comments then your problem seems to be more related to a general dispatch problem rather then the specification pattern. given your interfaces you could more simply do.

```
class BankFacade
{
    public Send(IBlueBank bank)
    {
        // validate with specification
        // do stuff with IBlueBank
    }

    public Send(IRedBank bank)
    {
        // validate with specification
        // do stuff with IRedBank
    }

    //...
}
```

thinking some more may you could do something along the lines of

```
class Parser
{
    static class RedBankSpecification : ISpecification<XElement>
    {
        public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(XElement element)
        {
            return element.Value.equals("RED");
        }
    }

    public void Parse(XDocument doc)
    {
        var rspec = new RedBankSpecification();

        foreach(XElement e in doc)
        {
            if (r.IsSatisfiedBy(e))
            {
                IRedBank bank = new RedBank(e);
                bankFacade.Send(bank);
            }
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

however you may not really need the pattern and you shuoldn't try to shoehorn the problem into it

Comment: Thanks for your example code. This kind of gave me basic idea. I am gonna try it. wish me luck. thanks again....

Comment: Why are you thanking people and not marking the answer as accepted?  Did you need more info or the answer did not help?